# Data import and migrate using Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

I need to load data from an old DB into a migrated schema of this DB using Doctrine migration system.

I guess Doctrine might help me in this process. 
I tried and lost a few hours using ETL scripts programs, without success.

From my point of view I need to :

- Create a DB with the V0 schema
- Load the data from the old DB (schema    are identical)
- Migrate DB to latest version using Doctrine migration
- Extract data
- Load it in the new DB

WHat do you think of this process?
Do you think it is feasable using Doctrine?

I tried a few searches on Google without success.

I am currently reviewed the features of `Doctrine_Core` class.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to migrate data from one database to another using Doctrine.

It sounds like you're trying to do a one-time database revision and migration and that your applications are not currently written using Doctrine.  In that scenario, database abstraction has little or no benefit, unless you're also rewriting the applications to use it.

If you have no prior experience using Doctrine then I seriously doubt that writing custom migration classes in it will be easier than doing it with whatever database API you are already experienced using.  It makes sense to use the migration classes (some times) if you are already using Doctrine for your development.  Otherwise it's another layer and API you don't need.

I'm using Doctrine 1.2, which has some nice features for migrations but also a number of bugs and omissions of expected functionality.  Reportedly version 2 improves on this but I haven't used it yet.

Comment: Actually I did use Doctrine to upgrade my DB schema to the current version that my (old) data need to be transformed.

Comment: @ant1j Then what is your question?

Comment: I was loooking for a right process to import data to the new DB (as I can't only take the old one and upgrade it)